# Adding feature class name automatically from overlay layer into attribute of clipped layer while iterating clip

Tags: qgis, clip, iteration, qgis-3

I am trying to clip the road layer to district boundary layer in QGIS using clip and enabling 'iterate' option and I get the clipped road layers of individual districts. Later, I need to add the district names into the road layer attributes under field 'dist_name' manually. In order to add the dist_name I am opening the road layer and entering the district name using field calculator one by one.

Is there any way how I can add it automatically doing the clipping process?

[image]

Comment: I removed your PyQGIS tag because your question contains no code.

Comment: Please specify which QGIS version you're using, because in 3.4 there's no option to iterate during clip.

Comment: I am using Qgis 3.10.2

Comment: I found iterate option in 3.4.15

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing the label-placement of your district boundaries I assume they are actually polygons. If so, you can do the following:

Instead of using "clip", try "intersection". This will cut your roads at the edges of each district and add their attributes to the roads.

1) Two layers. A) Roads (not clipped) and B) Districts (labels show district names)

[image]

2) Run intersection tool. Choose roads as input and districts as overlay

[image]

3) The result. The roads are clipped into pieces at the district borders and contain the attributes of their intersecting district layer.

[image]

Additional info: In case your roads are splitted over several layers, you can use "batch processing" (you can find this option at the bottom of intersection tool).

Answer (score 0):

If your districts are actual polygons, you can do join by location (after clip) and get the name of the polygon attached to each line. You may have to use field calculator too.